# Appending to different columns of CSV in R

Tags: r, shell

I have a CSV file and i m running two different shell scripts to write in to it. The header of the CSV looks like this.

```
date,C1,C2,C3
```

The first script writes the date in the date column. So it looks something like this

```
date,C1,C2,C3
2013-07-03,
```

Now i am stuck as to how to append to the C1,C2,C3 column using R, in the second shell script. I tried the following code

```
d<-data.frame(1,2,3)
write.table(d, file="my.csv", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

But its appending to the next line. I dont want to combine both the shell scripts. If there is a way to append to the respective columns through shell script also, that would be helpful also. Thank You in  advance.

Comment: How are the two scripts run, in respect to each other? E.g. is the first script run once, and then the second and that is the end of it? Or do you have to run the first script that adds to the result of the second script?

Comment: Well the the first script generates a file which is used in the second one. And yeah first script is run once and then then the second and that's about the end of it.

Comment: Then do as @agstudy suggested in the answers: Run script 1 as normal, then second script loads result from script 1, adds columns according to whatever logic you are applying, and then saves result in another file or overwrites previous file.

Answer (score 1):

This looks over-complicated. Personally I avoid using `append=TRUE` and specially with different columns. One solution is to save the result of the first script, read it at the end of the second script and save once without appending.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
cat(paste(d, collapse=","), file="my.csv", append=TRUE)
```